# Displaying Errors from Sitecore PowerShell Using Remoting

Tags: powershell-extensions

Using the remoting capabilities in [Sitecore PowerShell Extensions](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx), I'm trying to execute some PowerShell remotely and ensure that any errors that occur display in the local console. How can I do that?

Here's what I have:

```
Import-Module -Name SPE

$session = New-ScriptSession -Username "admin" -Password "b" -ConnectionUri "http://sitecore.local"
$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -AsJob -ScriptBlock { 
    $templatesPath = "master:/sitecore/content/data/tempdata"

    if (Test-Path $templatesPath) {
        if ((Get-Item $templatesPath).HasChildren -eq "True") {
            $children = Get-ChildItem $templatesPath
            foreach ($childItem in $children) {
                "Deleting temp content at $($childItem.FullPath)"

                # I recognize this next line does not work
                # It's wrong on purpose to test what happens when an error occurs
                Remove-Item "$($childItem.FullPath)" -Force -Recurse
            }
        }
    }
}

Wait-RemoteScriptSession -Session $session -Id $jobId -Delay 1 -Verbose
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

If I check the logs after execution I see that an error occurred, but I don't see the error in the console where I executed the script.

Answer (score 4):

Dan, a very good question. Bringing back error messages through the SPE Remoting is quite tricky because of the way PowerShell handles streams of data. Script output is handled one way, and errors (or informational messages) are handled in a different way.

Here are some possible ways for you to troubleshoot.

**Example:** Run script without the use of asynchronous jobs. If the script turns fairly quickly then it won't be an issue in your testing. Running as a scheduled task, however, may be more suitable for async jobs. The **ErrorRecord** object is returned in the output.

```powershell
Import-Module -Name SPE

$session = New-ScriptSession -Username michael -Password b -ConnectionUri http://spe
Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock { 
    $templatesPath = "master:/sitecore/content/pathdoesnotactuallyexist"
    Remove-Item "$($templatesPath)"-Force -ParameterDoesNotActuallyExist
}

Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

Using the above example you will see this in the Windows PowerShell ISE (remotely).

[image: ISE error message without async job]

Now you may be thinking, *"Well what if the job does take a while to run?"*

**Example:** Run script asynchronously. A string version of the error is returned.

```powershell
Import-Module -Name SPE

$session = New-ScriptSession -Username michael -Password b -ConnectionUri http://spe
$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    try {
        $templatesPath = "master:/sitecore/content/pathdoesnotactuallyexist"
        Remove-Item "$($templatesPath)"-Force -ParameterDoesNotActuallyExist
    } catch {
        $_
    }
} -AsJob

Wait-RemoteScriptSession -Session $session -Id $jobId -Delay 1

Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

Using the above example you will see this int he Windows PowerShell ISE (remotely).

[image: ISE error message with async job]

This currently looks a little less polished but still gets the job done.

### Update

If you desire for your script to return an error message for commands that normally continue, add `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` in your `ScriptBlock`.

**Example:** Run script asynchronously and stop on any error.

```powershell
Import-Module -Name SPE

$session = New-ScriptSession -Username michael -Password b -ConnectionUri http://spe
$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    try {
        $templatesPath = "master:/sitecore/content/pathdoesnotactuallyexist"
        Get-Item "$($templatesPath)"-Force
    } catch {
        $_
    }
} -AsJob

Wait-RemoteScriptSession -Session $session -Id $jobId -Delay 1

Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

[image: Error on Get-Item command]

#### Update 2

Version 4.4.1+ should include support for Write-Verbose and other `Write-` commands.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/824).

[image: Streams]

Comment: Unfortunately, the error that is thrown by `Remove-Item` if the path is not found does not get bubbled up to be caught when it's executed from a remoting session. When I run your code from your second example, I see the right result. However, if I remove the `-ParameterDoesNotActuallyExist` parameter and instead allow it to use an incorrect path, it fails silently. Are there multiple categories of errors that I need to handle differently?

Comment: The current version 4.2 really optimizes the authoring experience from within the Sitecore interface. I would encourage you to consider authoring more complex scripts there and then applying to the remoting script when ready.

Comment: Oops, I see your updated question now. The errors that are bubbled up include those that have syntax issues. If you ran for example `Get-Item` on a path that does not exist, the error doesn't stop the script from running. It's also more of a warning that the path doesn't exist. You could try using `Test-Path` in more places and `Write-Output` to return result messages back.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I guess my underlying question is more about making sure that all the errors get returned to the remote session, more than this specific case (obviously, I'll fix this one :) ). My concern is if some new error occurs, but in the remote session everything looks OK. I wouldn't know it had failed.

Comment: I completely agree and understand Dan. If I can come up with some additional examples to help out I'll update the answer. Feel free to share more barebones examples of what kind of message you need trapped and I'll see if it's possible.

Comment: Thanks! You should be able to run the code from my question in a remote session as-is to see the exact issue I described. (You'll need to create some content items below `/sitecore/content/data/tempdata` so there's something to delete.)